I want to populate my dropdown field (HTML Form) with dynamic data coming from a Google Sheet
reaching out because this is my first time doing this.
the fields in my html form
Say I have an HTML form with two fields for now (please disregard the other fields in the photo).
First is named SCREENING DATE field, and a CLIENT NAME field. The latter is a select or dropdown field and I want to populate it with data coming from a sheet named FORM SETTINGS, range E2:E.
Here's a link to the reference sheet for viewing:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I7nRu8B0ZsB-0YMkUnZk_r76l0yRAlZh1uZLsYDjAL0/edit?usp=sharing
Currently, the only function I have is for the value in the SCREENING DATE field to reflect on cell A2 in the same FORM SETTINGS sheet (this function is called upon loading of form and upon changing the selected date).
Here's what happens for better visualization of the function:
This is upon page loading
This is upon page loading, SCREENING DATE shows the current date, which is then reflected on cell A2.
And this is when I change the date
And this is when the date is changed in SCREENING DATE, which also reflects on cell A2, and when there are entries for that chosen date, it appears on the columns on the right (emphasis on FULL NAME as it is what I want to use).
So to summarize what happens in the reference sheet:
Based on the date that reflects on cell A2, it then calls for entries or names registered within that date to populate the E column or Full Name column. And if it helps to know, these names are coming from another worksheet named REGISTRATION RECORD (you can also see this on the reference sheet I attached above).
Now, here is what I want to do:
Populate my CLIENT NAME dropdown with data or values from range E2:E. It does not matter if it is empty or has a list of names, as long as it populates my dropdown with its available values (in real time with if possible). If not possible, then maybe call for an update for the dropdown upon loading of page and whenever a change of date happens in SCREENING DATE field.
Thanks in advance. And if there's anything that I can provide more, please let me know!
I've tried tried and tried browsing from forums and even watching video tutorials but since most of the dynamic list they pertain to are not changing based on date like mine, I kinda have a hard time navigating through them. Again, this is my first time doing this so I kinda get confused easily, so apologies if this is supposed to be an easy one and I'm already asking for help - but I'm here to learn and digest the right way to do this so if anyone can help, please 

Please review how to ask a question in order to seek help in this platform and have your problem solved. Link
